# Laravel broadcasting - use job ID as an 'order' property

Tags: laravel, broadcast

I want to send some sort of (unique, auto-incrementing) number as part of the payload of an event - so that the consumer can, for example, know it should ignore an 'updated' event if the event is older than a previous 'update' event it received.

I see I can add a `broadcastWith` method to my event, where I could add such a number, which I'm storing in some table.

But, I don't really need to create a new number. The ID of the job in the `jobs` table will work just fine. So, how can I make Laravel automatically add a property, say `order`, to this event before it is broadcast and make the value of `order` to `id` column from the `jobs` table? Is there a way to get it in the `broadcastWith` method?

I had previously thought of using a timestamp as the 'order' but of course that won't help me or the consumer when two events have been created in a short-a timeframe as a computer can create two events.

**UPDATE**
Looks like I haven't worded it well and people are confused as to what I'm looking for. In hindsight, I shouldn't of added the criteria that it must be the job id that gets included in the payload. The main thing I'm after is a unique, auto-incrementing ID in each broadcast event. For example, I have an UserUpdated event. Say the a user is updated twice - my SPA that is consuming the events needs to know which event is the newer one, otherwise the SPA might display outdated info. If the events are delivered sequentially, then this problem won't happen. But, especially as I'm relying on a third-party service (Pusher) to deliver the events to the SPA, I don't want to assume / trust that the events will always be delivered in the same order they were sent to Pusher.

Comment: You're broadcasting an event, what does this have to do with a job? If you have a listener that queues a job and then the job is run, that's many steps removed and long after an event is fired.

Comment: @miken32 (unless I'm wrong) each broadcast event is added to the job queue, so there is essentially a one-to-one mapping of jobs to broadcast events. The higher the job id, the newer the broadcast event is, so the job id will work well for what I want. The jobs are created at the time you queue it / queue the event to be broadcast, sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Hi such a nice requirement, i have been working on a POCO and here are some snippets, you do not need broadcast at all. Of course you need to have the queue worker up and running
[Running The Queue Worker](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

1. On your order controller, i guess you need the update method to dispatch the job before commiting.

   ```
   function update(Request $req)
   {
    $data= Order::find($req->id);
    $data->amount=$req->amount; //example field
    PostUpdateOrderJob::dispatch($data)->beforeCommit();
    $data->save();  
   }
   ```

**Important:** Why before commit and not after commit: Setting the after_commit configuration option to true will also cause any queued event listeners, mailables, notifications, and broadcast events to be dispatched after all open database transactions have been committed.

2. Your PostUpdateOrderJob class

   ```
   ?php

   namespace App\Jobs;    
   use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
   use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
   use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
   use App\Models\Order;
   use Throwable;

   class PostUpdateOrderJob implements ShouldQueue
   {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

     /**
      * The number of times the job may be attempted.
      *
      * @var int
      */
    public $tries = 25;

    /**
     * The maximum number of unhandled exceptions to allow before failing.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $maxExceptions = 3;


    protected $order;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
     $this->order=$order;    
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {                   
     $this->order->update(['jobid'=>$this->job->getJobId()]);              
    }

    public function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
         // Send user notification of failure, etc...
         //Several options on link below
         //https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs
    }

   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Well php has a function called `time()` which returns the current unix time in seconds, so you can just use that in your broadcast event.

In your broadcast event, you can add this `time` to the public class properties, which would then be available through the event payload:

```php
class MyBroadcastEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    public $time;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->time = time();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, your question is kind of confusing to be honest.

Comment: hi, he clearly referred to the job id, thanks for your solution which can be a good alternative.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but no that won't work well. I have already thought of your idea, and I mentioned it in the last paragraph of my question (albeit a little cryptographic admittedly). It won't work in the case where multiple events are created in the same second. Even microtime() won't be good enough. If multiple events have the same timestamp, then event consumers won't be able to tell which event is the newer one.

Comment: Batch dispatch?

Comment: @Dan. it sounds like you're basically trying to recreate couchdb functionality in your app. I think you should consider just using the `updated_at` value and use websockets for when new things happen and need updating in the app.